# jQuery conditions

Tags: jquery, slider

So I'm doing a sort of slider, and I'm having problems with making it hide the down button when it is all the way down, and vice versa with the up button.

```
var amount = $('slide').attr('number');
$('span#up').click(function(){
$('div#container').animate({marginTop: '+=' + playerH});
position--;
if (position < amount){
    $('span#up').hide();}
else {
    $('span#up').show();
    }
});

$('span#down').click(function(){
$('div#container').animate({marginTop: '-=' + playerH});
position++;console.log(amount);
if (position > amount){
    $('span#down').hide();}
else {
    $('span#down').show();
    }
```

Basically the amount variable is the amount of slides inside the container.
I create a slide element and put number="4" if it is the fourth slide, so it can count the amount of slides.

I hope I'm being clear enough :D.

Comment: And... ? what is the problem ?

Comment: can you paste in some of the html (simplified) that this drives?  Also, did you initialize the position variable to 0?

Comment: I dont understand if you need help with something why don't people at least make the code cleaner for us to read through and not having to check where a function starts and ends etc...

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you are not re-showing #up on the down click and #down on the up click. Once one of them is hidden, how would you reshow them with your code? I would group the show/hide code into one function and call it from both event handlers, something like (simplified pseudo code just to give you the idea):

```
var totalSlides = 4;
var position = 0;

function checkStuff( pos )
{
  $('div#container').animate({marginTop: '+=' + playerH});

  if ( pos === 0 )
  {
    $('span#up').hide();
  }
  else
    $('span#up').show();

  if ( pos === totalSlides )
  {
    $('span#down').hide();
  }
  else
    $('span#down').show();      
}

$('span#down').click(function(){

  position++;
  checkStuff( position );

});

$('span#up').click(function(){

  position--;
  checkStuff( position );

});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how your code differs from mine? Is it that it is inside a function?

Comment: because in yours you are only calling $('span#down').hide() and $('span#down').show() in the $('span#down').click() event - you never change the visibility of the down arrow after the up arrow has been clicked. So once you've gone all the away down the down arrow will never be shown again. My example sets both up and down arrows on up/down events.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is your problem, but you have to show the up button when the down is click (and vice versa)